# OpenShift OnPrem Dynamic PVC provisioning

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I have the latest version of OpenShift installed on-prem. I am trying to find a way to dynamically provision PVCs, what is the best solution available for on-prem version of OpenShift? I have been looking into minIO and longhorn but I could not integrate with my OnPrem solution yet.
Can anyone provide some insight here?

Thanks,
Tintu

Answer (score 0):

If you have an NFS server somewhere, it is very easy to setup a nfs dynamic provisionner: [Check NFS client provisionner project here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner)

Another approach is to install and use the CSI driver corresponding to your storage devices
[Kubernetes CSI drivers are here](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/drivers.html) (There is also a beta version of the NFS CSI driver...)

ANd BTW, Minio provides "object stirage" with an AWS S3 compatible interface, there is no such thing as "dynamic object storage" allocation in OCP/K8S...